# How to get a single MS Teams message from an URL with Microsoft Graph Rest API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the MS Teams message [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) with the Microsoft Graph Rest API from an URL.
The URL I copied from the MS Team App with "copy link".
The resulting URL is like: https://teams.microsoft.com/messages/19:xzyys.......@thread.tacv2/123456789?tenantId=.....

I cannot find an API endpoint in the docs, which can take that URL as the source for fetching a message object [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0).

I searched in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what type of Message it is eg is a chat message or a channel messages you can use either https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

From what you posted if you just want to get a particular message is a chat https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

where

19:xzyys.......@thread.tacv2

is the chat-id and

123456789

is the messageid